# ATMs on ferries from Europe to Dover

Tags: uk, atms

I’ll be going to UK in a couple of weeks and I was wondering if there are ATMs on the ferries from either Calais or Dunkirk to Dover where I could withdraw GBP using either a Visa or a Mastercard (both are debit cards!) without being robbed blind on charges.

Since I’m going by coach, I probably cannot use an ATM on the docks in Dover.

Comment: I would expect ATM charges to be highest on the ferries, a little lower in Dover, and lowest at a normal high street ATM at your destination.

Comment: Both Visa and Mastercard will rob you blind on charges and interest. Getting cash with a credit card is a terrible idea. Use a debit card instead. If you absolute have to use a credit card, pre-load it with cash and make sure you NEVER carry any balance before the cash advance is paid back.

Comment: @Hilmar I should have specified that I only have debit cards. Your comment is obviously still of use for other travellers though.

Comment: What in earth do you mean Mastercard and Visa will rob you kind? They have no influence on the fees a card issuer may charge.

Comment: OP - why do you want to withdraw GBP on the ferry?

Comment: @Turkeyphant just so that I have a little cash, e.g. for a taxi or something.

Comment: @arne Why would you want cash for a taxi or indeed anything else? Everywhere takes card. And anyway there will be ATMs when you disembark.

Comment: @Turkeyphant …until one place does not. Think Ice cream parlour or Hot Dog stand. Or the card terminal is simply broken.

Comment: lol, it would be a lot harder to avoid an ATM when arriving in Dover for long enough to find a merchant that doesn't take card.

Comment: The number of places not taking cards will be lower than the number of places *only* taking cards.

Comment: @Marianne013 I noticed that too. You couldn't even buy ice cream on the beach with cash. So I shouldn't have worried.

Comment: @Turkeyphant Yes they do. Mastercard and Visa's network rules dictate a fee paid by the issuing bank to the ATM owner. This is the origin of the fee charged by the bank to the customer. In most cases, the ATM owner wants more, so they tack on a separate fee.

Comment: @user71659 they influence it but they don't mandate the bank fees I'm referring to in any way

Answer (score 6):

If you use P&O Ferries: (Calais - Dover)

> Commission-free foreign exchange is available to all passengers from the bureau de change and ATM machines are located throughout the vessel.

[Source](https://www.poferries.com/en/routes/dover-to-calais/onboard/foreign-exchange)

DFDS: (Dover - Dunkirk) & (Calais - Dover)

> Is there an ATM onboard? **We don't have an ATM onboard**. You can pay by card, please see the payment types available.

[Source](https://ferrygogo.com/route/dover-dunkirk/)

Irish Ferries: (Calais - Dover)

> Both Irish ferries and Stena line terminals have ATM's but it might be an idea to just change some £ Sterling at a UK post office or M&S store.

[Source](https://www.tripadvisor.in/ShowTopic-g186605-i90-k4999388-ATM_Cash_Machine_in_Dublin_Ferry_Terminal-Dublin_County_Dublin.html)

Comment: sources please?

Comment: @njzk2 good point, added them. Thanks.